# Error Response Code: 500 while running the Load test over the JMeter for 2hrs

Tags: nginx, jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am getting Error **Response Code: 500** for several requests while running the load for 2hrs over the JMeter. It is very difficult to debug the issue as there are no unexpected exceptions over the logs as well. It is negligible if the count is less but it is getting higher day by day. We are using NGINX as a web server and we have two instances of the same. The load is triggered from the separate instance which is hosted on the cloud. The RDS max connection possible is **10000** and also all the instances are of big size. Could anyone help with the same? Further details can be  given if required.

***2022-03-31 15:56:44,881 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: Cause: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500***

Load test was running on the JMeter in a separate instance. An unexpected 500 Internal server errors popped out due to which many APIs got failed.

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. So look into server logfiles for more information.

Comment: To which server logs do I have to check? Webserver?

Comment: Yes the Webserver log

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 500 description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 **Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request**.
>
> This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Usually, this indicates the server cannot find a better 5xx error code to response. Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

If the error occurs only under the heavy load and doesn't occur when the load is less most probably it indicates that your application is overloaded and cannot properly respond to the requests.

In order to find out the root cause you can take the following steps:

1. Check your application logs for any suspicious entries, normally errors should be logged with stacktraces so you should get way more information than just HTTP Status code 500
2. Make sure that your application is [properly configured for high load](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/5-ways-to-improve-your-production-web-application-server-setup), web servers, databases, load balancers and other middleware default configuration is good for debugging but you need to properly tune everything before going live
3. Make sure that your application has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, etc. as it might be simply lack of resources, it can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) or an [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) if it's in place
4. Re-run your test with [profiling tool telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) enabled, this way you will be able to precisely identify the bottleneck and the root cause.